# Trying to Make an R Function to Retrieve a Variable Name

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm new to R and trying to create a function which I think should be fairly straight-forward but I'm stuck. I have a data frame with states and their populations for various years. I want to make a function which finds the highest population in a given year and returns the corresponding state name. I know how to retrieve the max population, but I don't know how to use that to look up the corresponding state name. Here's my code to find the max population:

`max(dfStates$Jul2011)`

Now, putting that into a function so far I have:

`lotsOfPeeps<-function(dfStates){
  highestPop<-max(dfStates$Jul2011)
  return(highestPop)}`

So, when I run `lotsOfPeeps(dfStates)` right now it just returns the highest population value. How would I add to it to retrieve the state name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which.max` which will return index of the highest value of population and use it to get corresponding state name. Assuming the column with state name is called `StateName`, you can do

```
lotsOfPeeps<-function(dfStates){
   hihest_pop_state <- dfStates$StateName[which.max(dfStates$Jul2011)]
   return(hihest_pop_state)
}

lotsOfPeeps(dfStates)
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation to make the function more flexible. This will likely be slower than `which.max`.

```
lotsOfPeeps<-function(df, column,target_column){
  highestPop<-df[df[column]==max(df[column]),target_column]

  return(highestPop)
  }
```

To get it in "column-like" format, we can wrap `highestPop` in `[[` as suggested by @akrun such that:

```
highestPop<-df[df[column]==max(df[column]),][target_column]
```

Testing with iris:

```
lotsOfPeeps(iris,"Sepal.Length","Species") # name maintained,can be better named
[1] virginica
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Result if highestPop is wrapped in `[[`:

```
lotsOfPeeps(iris,"Sepal.Length","Species")
      Species
132 virginica
```

Comment: Could wrap with `[[` to make it a vector